# How to find out Google API related method

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-client

I need to get the stars amount on apps, and I found this Google API

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews#retrieving_a_set_of_reviews

But I am going to do it server to server, therefore I use server account solution

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

This example is for sqladmin, I don't know where to get `androidpublisher`'s sample, here is my code

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'account.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

from apiclient.discovery import build

try:
    service = build('androidpublisher', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Nothing went wrong so far, I just need to know what is the next step to achieve this `GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/your_package_name/reviews?
access_token=your_auth_token`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your trying to access the [Review.list()](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/list) method.

Try putting this after your value for `service`

```
reviews_list = service.reviews().list(packageName=package_name).execute()
```

For reference there is a similar example in the python directory of the [android-play-publisher-api](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v2/python) repository.

A similar method is run at [this point](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v2/python/basic_list_apks_service_account.py#L66) in the code for the [Edits.apks: list](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/apks/list) method

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works, can I filter the data by timestamps, such as seconds between 1522195200 and 1522156395

Comment: Not a problem at all, glad to be of help. I don't believe you can directly filter based on timestamps but you should be able to collect the reviews as a list using `reviews_list.get('reviews', None)` and then filter out items looking at the `'lastModified` field of each review element. See: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews#resource

Comment: It's so weird, I set maxResutls as 500, but each game feedback different result, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.igg.pokerdeluxepro&showAllReviews=true this one only return 10, why is that?